# why Kubuntu KDE default Start Menu Icon not using Kubuntu icon just like Ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, icons

I wonder, why Kubuntu team does not use Kubuntu Icon in KDE Start menu just like Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [quote](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2010/10/10/%23kubuntu-devel.html#t20:07) Jonathan Riddell:

> I'm very happy with the upstream KDE artwork and don't see any reason to change it

Since Riddell and other members of the Kubuntu community are happy with the artwork KDE ships, they prefer to stick with it instead of customizing it for Kubuntu. They encourage people interested in working on the artwork to do so upstream with KDE so that other distributions (including Kubuntu) can benefit from the work.

Answer (score 2):

One of the principles of the Kubuntu Team is to keep the KDE desktop on Kubuntu as close to the default KDE desktop as possible. Changing such icons would violate this principle.

However, since all is open source software, anybody can customize their own desktop anyway they like.

Comment: hmm.. Just like slackware did. But I agreed with Kubuntu team keep KDE to original one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Kubuntu team likes to keep KDE fairly.. KDE. I believe there is an icon somewhere it is just not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have the elementary theme and an 'e' instead of the KDE icon. From Kubuntu's stand point keep true to KDE, but from yours change it to suit yourself. It is your computer so personalise it.

Comment: Hi! You said you use the elementary theme in KDE? How to do that? I'm looking for an adaption of the elementary look for months now and I can't get it right. Which panel appearance to use? Any hint would be greatly appreciated ... thx anyways, piedro

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the plasmoid > settings > change the icon...
kde is "that"customizable